# How to color rows in macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a working macro that adds a single blank row every 6th row and it works great! I have an issue though, which is so simple but it's not working :S
I was hoping to color these new rows color: .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893 and only cells between columns A to H.

I have no idea where to add this in this code. Can someone help me?

```
Dim NumRowsToInsert As Long
Dim RowIncrement As Long
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastEvenlyDivisibleRow
Dim i As Long

NumRowsToInsert = 1
RowIncrement = 6
Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastEvenlyDivisibleRow = Int(LastRow / RowIncrement) * RowIncrement
    If LastEvenlyDivisibleRow = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = LastEvenlyDivisibleRow To 1 Step -RowIncrement
        .Range(i & ":" & i + (NumRowsToInsert - 1)).Insert xlShiftDown
    Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it right after adding the new rows.

```
For i = LastEvenlyDivisibleRow To 1 Step -RowIncrement
    .Range(i & ":" & i + (NumRowsToInsert - 1)).Insert xlShiftDown
    .Range("A" & i & ":H" & i + (NumRowsToInsert - 1)).Interior.TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
Next i
```

Note that this particular TintAndShade comes up as no colour for me...

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked. Much appreciated! @vacip

Answer (score 0):

Inserting and setting the color row by row it no ideal and slow. A better way is to insert all of them in a single shot:

```
Sub InsertRowsAndSetColor()

  Const StartRow = 1
  Const NumRowsToInsert = 1
  Const RowIncrement = 6

  Dim ws As Worksheet, rg As Range, rowCount As Long, r As Long
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  rowCount = ws.UsedRange.row + ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

  ' exit if not enough rows
  If rowCount <= StartRow + RowIncrement Then Exit Sub

  ' collect all the rows requireing an insertion
  Set rg = ws.Rows(StartRow + RowIncrement)
  For r = StartRow + RowIncrement To rowCount Step RowIncrement
    If NumRowsToInsert > 1 Then
      Set rg = Union(rg, ws.Range(ws.Rows(r), ws.Rows(r + NumRowsToInsert - 1)))
    Else
      Set rg = Union(rg, ws.Rows(r))
    End If
  Next

  ' insert the rows
  rg.Insert xlShiftDown

  ' set the interior for the new rows within A:H
  With Intersect(rg.offset(-NumRowsToInsert), ws.Columns("A:H")).Interior
    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I like the concept, but are you sure there is a measurable difference in runtime if both screen updating and calculation are turned off?

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked. Much appreciated! @florentbr